# ManipulationBoundaryFeedback does not work in webbrowser in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

i am using ManipulationBoundaryFeedback  to avoid the window from being  dragged on touch device , this works fine will all the other controls except when the webbrowser has a scrollbar. any work Around for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could turn of this behavior for the whole system.
Open registry and set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch Bouncing to 0

Comment: Nice one. Problem also exists when you fit a webbrowser view perfectly into a window, and makes the application looks scrappy. This fixes it.