# How do I prevent touch feedback on a Winforms WebBrowser in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I'm using the WinForms version of `<WebBrowser>` in my WPF app, *a la* `<WindowsFormsHost>` because in general it works a lot better than the Windows.Controls version. However I have one problem that has to do with touch screens.

Normally I set the `ManipulationBoundaryFeedback` event handler on controls to immediately handle the event, thereby preventing any boundary feedback, and I've tried to do so with this code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<WindowsFormsHost IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationBoundaryFeedback="WindowsFormsHost_OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback">
    <forms:WebBrowser />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void WindowsFormsHost_OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

On ordinary WPF controls, generally speaking, this works. And what I mean by "works" is that if you use your finger on the touch screen and drag up or down, you don't get the effects of touch screen *intertia*; that is, it doesn't shift *the entire window* up or down once you hit the boundary.

Here's a picture to illustrate what's happening:

[image: animated gif of touch screen issue]

As you can see, if I drag down within the browser, it pulls the entire window with it. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried using `OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback` instead?

Comment: @Night5h4d3 do you have a typo in your comment? Because that is literally what I used.

Comment: sorry; have you tried adding the event handler to the web browser tag?

Comment: The Windows Forms version of that control doesn't have a ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event; the manipulation events are part of WPF (and WinForms predates that)

Comment: In that case you'd need to write special handling for the [WM_Gesture message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242(v=vs.85).aspx). [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940542(v=vs.85).aspx) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off this behavior for the whole system:

Open registry ( `run regedit command` ) and set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch` `Bouncing` to `0`;
if `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch` not exist `Bouncing` item, add it( **DWORD type, Not QWORD or String**) and set it value to `0`.

However, this is not a good approch, even if it solve my problem. Look at this [manipulationboundaryfeedback-does-not-work-in-webbrowser-in-wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855130/manipulationboundaryfeedback-does-not-work-in-webbrowser-in-wpf).

Comment: No idea why someone gave -1 for this.. This is EXACTLY what we needed for our kiosk application. No hacky code required. Thanks and to others - upvote this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answer but to prevent this unnecessary behavior simply inherit **WindowsFormsHost** class and override **OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback** like this:

```
public class MyClass : WindowsFormsHost
{

    // Override is optional to remove unnecessary behavior
    protected override void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        // uncomment this to use base class implementation
        //base.OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(e); 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Edited**

I have made a small test and added this code for my control

```
protected override void OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback(ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback");
}

private void MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback");
}
```

and **Output** was the following

> OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback
>
> MyControl_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback

So you can see that **OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback** launched first and then it invokes **ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEvent** handlers

Comment: This does not work. I mentioned in the original description that the ManipulationBoundaryFeedback event handler does not handle this for a WindowsFormsHost element (or for any inherited elements), I mentioned again in the comments to Enfyve that this does not work, and I just now whipped up a quick test project just to ensure I'm not going crazy. This definitely does not work.

Comment: **Overriding OnManipulationBoundaryFeedback** IS NOT THE SAME that adding event handler to ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEvent. I know that it WORKS 100% because today i had that issue and fixed this like this.

Comment: watch this video to see that this code works https://vimeo.com/237103516